# ngx-datatable: How to make tooltips appear

Tags: ngx-datatable

When using the ngx-datatable library, sometimes a tooltip appears when hovering over a table cell and sometimes not. I have a table with custom cell templates and would like to make these tooltips appear.

Here are examples where tooltips appear when hovering over table cells:

- http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#rx
- http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#dark
- http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#bootstrap

And here are examples where they don't appear:

- http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#virtual-scroll
- http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#inline
- http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#flex

Can someone please explain how/why the tooltips sometimes appear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out this is due to the `title` attribute being set on the cells. I'm not sure why it is set in some cases and not others, but at least I can add it in my own templates.

Answer (score 2):

I also was able implement tooltip with **ngbTooltip**.

```
<ng-template let-column="column"
      ngx-datatable-header-template>
      <div container="body"
           [ngbTooltip]="'tooltip text">
           header 1
      </div>
</ng-template>
```

Note that tooltip was not displayed properly until I added `container="body"`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the tooltip attribute for bootstrap and data-tooltip for materialize. The basic attribute would be title.

```
tooltip="your tooltip"
```

But there is some conflict with the template class so its possible that you lose the sort functionality if you want tooltips in the column headers. There is workaround like this.

```js
<ngx-datatable-column  [width]="500" prop="name" headerClass="text-left">
                    <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn">
                        <div class="d-inline-block datatable-header-cell-wrapper" tooltip="your tooltip" container="body" [adaptivePosition]="false" placement="top">
                            <span class="datatable-header-cell-label draggable" (click)="sort()">Column Header</span>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
```

Comment: it works with adding this props : container="body" [adaptivePosition]="false"